# Creating dockerfile for golang web application

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I've tried following the tutorials out there, but for some reason, because of how my directories are set up, I can't seem to make a dockerfile to create a docker container for my web app so I can run it on multiple devices using docker.

Here is my project structure:

```
MyApp
    /cmd
        /web
            - main.go
            - middleware.go
            - routes.go
    /pkg
        /somepackage
            - somegolangfile.go 
        /anotherpackageIuse
            - somegolangfile.go
    /templates
        -HTML files 
    go.mod
    go.sum
    .gitignore 
    Dockerfile
```

Here is the dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM golang:latest as build

WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN go build  -o app .
 
FROM alpine:latest as run
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app"]
```

I get the error that there are no go files in /build. This is correct and the error makes sense since the go files are in cmd/web/

However, I can't seem to fix it. I've tried doing:

```
FROM golang:latest as build

WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN go build  cmd/web/ -o app .
 
FROM alpine:latest as run
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/app"]
```

Key difference here is that I've swapped out `RUN go build  -o app .`with `RUN go build  cmd/web/ -o app .`, and yet I get the error that my sum.go and mod.go are not present in the directory, which is also true

How do I make a docker container for my web app, and have it build in which my go files are in a different directory? Also, when I run my web app normally, I used `go run cmd/web/*.go` in which all golang files in the cmd/web directory need to be run at the same time. Therefore, I also need my dockerfile to build and compile all the golang files together

=============================================

Comment: Try `go build -o app cmd/web` (or `./cmd/web` or `{module}/cmd/web`). The package you want to compile is `cmd/web` and you need to define `-o {output}` after `go build` and you don't need the second `.`. You can always `go build --help` too.

Comment: A couple of debugging pointers. You can comment failing and subsequent steps in a Dockerfile, build it and then run (a shell in) it to (a) run the `go build` in the container interactively to see what's failing and (b) e.g add. `RUN ls -la` steps to check folder content.

Comment: @DazWilkin, It still says the executor failed running with exit code 1 when trying to build. It also says no go files in /build
Thanks :)

Comment: Apologies, you do need to use `./cmd/web` (that'll teach me to try to do things from memory). And, per @ashutosh-singh, you should add a `RUN go mod tidy` (perhaps line #4) but `go.mod` and `go.sum` **are** included with by `COPY . .`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Radin Khosraviani,

`copy . .` will only copy the source code. You need to copy the `Go module files` as well.

Below I have modified your docker file and have added `COPY go.mod .` `COPY go.sum .` `RUN go mod download`

```
FROM golang:latest as build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Go module files
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

# Download the Go module dependencies
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o /myapp ./cmd/web
 
FROM alpine:latest as run

# Copy the application executable from the build image
COPY --from=build /myapp /myapp

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/myapp"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra dot in your build command and wrong arguments order:

```
RUN go build -o app ./cmd/web/...
```